# No available end point found exception while connecting to jbpm server

Tags: java, jbpm

I am getting below mentioned exception while connecting to the jbpm server(server 1) from java code deployed on tomcat server(server 2). I have checked for following scenarios

1. ssl certificate - it is correct
2. username and password - it is also correct
3. timeout error -No timeout error

Apart from these 3 scenarios, what could be the cause for this exception ? 
Below is the trace of the exception. Can anyone please help me in resolving this issue ?

Below is the error trace,

```
org.kie.server.common.rest.NoEndpointFoundException: No available endpoints found
    at org.kie.server.client.balancer.impl.AbstractBalancerStrategy.checkEmpty(AbstractBalancerStrategy.java:27)
    at org.kie.server.client.balancer.impl.RoundRobinBalancerStrategy.next(RoundRobinBalancerStrategy.java:37)
    at org.kie.server.client.balancer.LoadBalancer.getUrl(LoadBalancer.java:52)
    at org.kie.server.client.impl.AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.invoke(AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.java:809)
    at org.kie.server.client.impl.AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.makeHttpGetRequestAndCreateServiceResponse(AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.java:177)
    at org.kie.server.client.impl.KieServicesClientImpl.getServerInfo(KieServicesClientImpl.java:157)
    at org.kie.server.client.impl.KieServicesClientImpl.getCapabilitiesFromServer(KieServicesClientImpl.java:130)
    at org.kie.server.client.impl.KieServicesClientImpl.init(KieServicesClientImpl.java:85)
    at org.kie.server.client.impl.KieServicesClientImpl.<init>(KieServicesClientImpl.java:72)
    at org.kie.server.client.KieServicesFactory.newKieServicesClient(KieServicesFactory.java:101
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure your url will be like this- http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server
2. Ensure the containerId (you can also use the artifact name of your jbpm kjar) you have given to kieserverClient is right.
3. Ensure that Kjar is successfully deployed to kie server
4. Ensure jbpm is connected to Kie server. You can check this by deploying any sample project to kieserver.
5. Ensure that there no Jackson error in logs
6. Ensure the pom version of drools and kie server. what i used is this.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie.server</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-server-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.38.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <version>7.38.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
         <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
```